# Kaminari link URL routing issue in Rails :\

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, url, pagination, routes, kaminari

Wasn't able to find a similar thread, so here goes.

I just installed Kaminari for pagination. On the homepage, it worked perfectly, however, on my category pages it didn't:

Category URL:
**http://localhost:3000/categories/1**

The URLs Kaminari is creating, however, doesn't look right:
**http://localhost:3000/categories/show?id=1&page=2**

I would imagine it should be something like **http://localhost:3000/categories/1/?page=2** (which works when I type it in manually).

How might I get Kaminari to use the working link structure or is there something I need to change in routes.rb?

Thanks in advance for your help :) It is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was going on.

In my routes.rb I had

**get "categories/show"**

in addition to

**resources :categories**

as soon as I commented out the get line, it all worked perfectly :)